# Preblem with Theos made deb file

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, theos

I am new to iOS development....my iPhone 3Gs runs a jailbroken untethered iOS 6.0.1(according to snowbreeze,the app I jailbroke it with)...I installed Theos on my iPhone device following this site http://sites.google.com/site/theostutorials/ by ReverseEffect.Then I created an app called test and did all the things described in the tutorial(following http://sites.google.com/site/theostutorials/chapter-2-my-first-app/lesson-1-learning-nic). My deb package was successfully created and installed...but after Respringing I saw no icon ..I compiled again and did the respring thing but no icon...is it because the SDK is out of date?if yes,then how to get them?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go further in the tutorials, eventually they teach you how to use images in your app and finally applying an icon

Comment: Thanks...the problem has been solved.I actually had to respring several times and then surprisingly when I used iCleaner to clean up junks.The icon of my app showed up after respringing...really ghostly behavior.By the way...is there any way to install the deb files without the necessity of Respringing? I mean not all Cydia apps require respringing so why Theos made apps

Comment: you dont usually need to respring for theos apps unless its the first time your installing it, but some apps might need respringing because of the way theos build's the deb files, im pretty sure theres a way to stop that but i hardly ever have that problem

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers...well..Reverseeffect tutorial has been a good one for me.Can you please provide me with any good tutorial or book name that can help me do basic to advanced stuffs? Like making makefile or using custom library or frameworks or stacks like btStack....I got interested to iOs development actually when I saw they kept UART port in the dock port and saw some works done on it using iphone gcc...so I want to make some hardware level accessories for my phone as well as bluetooth based stuffs...so I need good guideline...I search google a lot but the tuts are so scattered

Comment: The community at www.ininjas.com is a very friendly and useful community, www.iphonedevwiki.net is also a good place to learn, just tap all pages on the navbar at the side and choos what you wnat to learn. Watching iKy1e's tumblr "blog" will teach you a lot too and finnaly going over several different tuorials (i can i message you the links) will teach you a lot. You can find me on ininjas as MeddleR and can (i)message me @ senam@y7mail.com, feel free to message me as much as you want and dont hesitate because you think you're annoying me good luck